# Display:none still occupying space

Tags: html, css

Okay so I'm having a bit of an issue with my display: none; CSS still occupying space on the page. You can see the problem here.

https://neueda-consulting.squarespace.com/news-blog

The content should be centred - not shifted off to the left. I need the rightSidebar to appear on other pages, so cannot physically remove the HTML.

Here's all I have managed to come up with.

```
#rightSidebar {
display:none !important;
width:0px !important;
}

aside{
  width:0px !important;
  display:none !important;
}

article{
  display:bock;
  width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey Gavin, clicked the linked, it took me to a log in page for square space. I'm not sure if that's the page you intended us to look at? Because I don't see "article" in the source!

Comment: Wow my bad. Let me update that.

Comment: Updated. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 2):

The shift has nothing to do with `display: none` not working. The problem is that you have specified a width on `.collection-type-blog #content`. Remove or override that and the content will appear centered.

Comment: Awesome thanks man. I'm using Squarespace so have been forced to negotiate a lot of the pre-built template's CSS. Overrode the width to 100% and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have caclulated width on `#content` block `calc(100% - 255px)`. So you have to calculate `margin-left` to get #content centered, so add rule below to content block:

```
.collection-type-blog #content{
  ...
  margin-left: calc(255px/2);
 }
```